# Excel IF statements "if cell contains" multiple output options

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

In Excel - if I have a cell (Ex: A1) that I can input either "2x6 DF#2","4x6 Borate", or "3x6 ACQ". . .basically any entry that contains either the text "DF", "Borate", or "ACQ". . .and I want Cell B1 to output "BF" I am using the following equation successfully:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("DF",A1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Borate",A1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ACQ",A1))),"BF","")
```

If I want the above stipulations to still be true. . .but I also want to be able to have the option of inputing "4x8 CDX", "2x6 OSB S1", "4x9 FRT PLY". . .basically any entry that contains either the text "CDX", "OSB", or "PLY". . . to output "SF" into Cell B1 - how do I accomplish that?

I would basically like a way that I can combine both of the following formulas. . .

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("DF",A1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Borate",A1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ACQ",A1))),"BF","")

=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CDX",A1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("OSB",A1)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("PLY",A1))),"SF","")
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"DF","Borate","ACQ"},A2)))),"BF",IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"CDX","OSB","PLY"},A2)))),"SF",""))
```

Or in this specific case:

```
=CHOOSE(ROUNDUP(MATCH(TRUE,(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"DF","Borate","ACQ","CDX","OSB","PLY"},A2))),0)/3,0),"BF","SF")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a lookup table:

[image]

Then reference that with this formula:

```
=INDEX(G:G,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($F$1:INDEX(F:F,MATCH("zzz",F:F)))/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($F$1:INDEX(F:F,MATCH("zzz",F:F)),A1))),1))
```

[image]